# Formatting and Substituting Into Queries Fails in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am doing some wrapping of queries in `TextClause` objects by using the SQLAlchemy's `text()` function. It appears that when I try to pass values to these parameters, they do not get substituted. I am pretty sure I am passing the parameters correctly (via dictionary).

Could there be an issue with having single quotes nearby a parameter to be subsituted? For instance, many of my queries have something like this:

```
':YYYY-01-01' as requested_date,
```

and

```
select concat('BB-:YY. ', as_name)
```

and

```
   ':YYYY-01-01'
```

Is it expected that these should work, assuming I pass a dictionary with `YY` and `YYYY` as keys that have appropriate values or are there caveats which would prevent this from succeeding?

Answer (score 1):

A sequence of characters like `:YY` will not be interpreted as a parameter placeholder if it appears within a string literal. So this won't work:

```py
    qry = text("select concat('BB-:YY. ', 'whatever')")
    results = conn.execute(qry, {"YY": "23"}).scalar()
```

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

You will need to re-work your SQL so the parameter placeholder is not inside a string literal:

```py
    qry = text("select concat('BB-' + :YY + '. ', 'whatever')")
    results = conn.execute(qry, {"YY": "23"}).scalar()

    print(results)  # BB-23. whatever
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution a lot. Do you, perchance, know if one can substitute in any place in the query, say, table names or just in the conditions section of the query?

Comment: Parameter substitution only works for *values* of things, not *names* of things. So, `SELECT * FROM :table_name` will not work. (At least, I have never seen a case where it does work.)